# psql insert statement returning baffling error

Tags: sql, insert, psql

Here's my table:

```
       Table "public.enrollment_tgelf"
         Column          |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------------------+------------------------+-----------
 course_entitlement_game | character varying(250) | 
 entitlement_subject     | character varying(250) | 
 school_name             | character varying(250) | 
 grade_level             | character varying(250) | 
 username                | character varying(250) |
```

Here's my insert statement:

```
    INSERT INTO enrollment_tgelf (course_entitlement_game, entitlement_subject, school_name, grade_level, username) 
    VALUES
    ("Lexica Vol 1","NA","tGELF","1","tgelf1");
```

Here's my error:

```
ERROR:  column "lexica vol 1" does not exist in enrollment_tgelf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes, not double quotes, to delimit string literals.

Comment: I'm new to psql and this isn't the first time I've been caught by single v double quotes. Can you explain when I should use single v. double quotes?

Comment: Single quotes are used for string values.  Double quotes are used for identifiers (such as names of tables or columns), generally only necessary when you have special characters or mixed case in the identifier.